# Increase the capacity of a RAIDZ1 vdev on ZFS

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas

I'm running FreeNAS on a **Mini-ITX** Box at home. I have 3x3TB HDDs in a RAIDZ1 udev. Now I'm running out of space. I have space for **one** additional HDD in my case. I want to convert the 3x3TB RAIDZ1 into a 4x3TB RAIDZ1.

Can I do that without sending a snapshot to some other disk, then completely rebuild the vdev/zpool and restoring the snapshot? Are there any other options I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The only way to increase space in raidz without rebuilding it is, while keeping the number of drives constant, to switch each drives to a bigger one and resilver each changed drive. After 3rd drive change and resilver you will get additional delta, equal to smallest space delta of one of the new drives.

Comment: +1 for BtrFS. Flamewar: ON :-). SCNR.

Comment: Never heard of it. Must be some academic beta of athoner one killer-fs.